# Como obter vários Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress

Como posso obter os valores de `Custom Fields` de posts diferentes sem precisar 
inserir vários `get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'key', true)`?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode buscar direto no banco de dados:

```
global $wpdb;

$resultado = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id,meta_value from {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'key';" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função:

$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);

foreach ( $custom_fields as $key => $value ) {

```
echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
```

}